# TemplateNotFoundError: Cannot render the template since its false, null or undefined

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

How do I define the template for `CompositeView`

```
define(function (require) {

    "use strict";

    var _          = require('underscore'),
        Marionette = require('backbone.marionette'),
        Row        = require('app/views/Dam/row'),
        tpl        = require('text!tpl/Dam/table.html'),
        template   = _.template(tpl);

    return Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

        tagName: "table",

        className: "table table-bordered",

        initialize: function (opt) {
            this.ev = opt.ev;
        },

        childView: Row, 

        childViewContainer: function(){
            return "tbody"
        },

        childViewOptions: function (model, index) {
            return {
                ev: this.ev
            }
        },

        onRender: function () {
             this.ev.trigger('App:Loading:Hide', true);
        }

   });

});
```

This compositeView is a child of Marionette.Region. I just trigger it like this `region.show(new CompositeView)`. I'm using latest Backbone as well as Marionette.

Comment: You need to add template. Read [this](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.compositeview.html).

Comment: I follow [this](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.compositeview.html#compositeviews-childviewcontainer) but I used requirejs to load the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you define template for any View

```
 Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

        tagName: "table",
        template : tpl,
        .....
        .....
```

it should work

Comment: it turn another error: `UndefinedTemplateError: Cannot render the template since it is null or undefined.`

Comment: are you sure that : tpl/Dam/table.html exists ? if you debug with chrome or firebug and you watch "tpl" what it gives you ?  if it is null then this is the problem that you have to fix

Comment: sorry those errors are actually belong to my itemView